# Spring Data JPA: Annotaton based works fine, but XML based not

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to convert Annotations based configuration to XMl based. Please, do not ask me why I am doing this. This became in principle.

Java class:

```
package org.cloudjumper.configs;

import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("org.cloudjumper")
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.cloudjumper.db.repositories.")
public class DataConfig {

    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "db.hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "db.hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROP_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "db.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));

        return properties;
    }

}
```

And part of XML is:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.cloudjumper"/>

    <bean class="org.cloudjumper.configs.DataConfig"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="org.cloudjumper.db.repositories"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/void"/>
        <property name="username" value="***"/>
        <property name="password" value="***"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.cloudjumper.db.tables"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="db.hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="db.hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

So Annotations works fine, but XML configurations returns error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaPlatformInaccessibleException: Unable to access TransactionManager or UserTransaction to make physical transaction delegate
```

UserRepository for more information:

```
package org.cloudjumper.db.repositories;

import org.cloudjumper.db.tables.Users;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

/**
 * Created by cloudjumper on 11/30/16.
 */
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Integer> {
    Users findByLogin(String login);
    Users findByName(String name);
}
```

They look identical. I gave up of trying 1 hour ago, so can anyone help me?

Comment: I haven't tested it yet... Add `<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>` to `<bean id="transactionManager">`.

Comment: Are you using `persistence.xml` in your application? If yes, is `transaction-type` in that file set to `JTA`? If yes, that is the source of the exception you are getting. Your configuration has a `JpaTransactionManager`, which is a non-JTA transaction manager whereas the JPA context requires it to be JTA-compliant. Also, it is preferable to use the `jpaVendorAdapter` instead of the `persistenceProviderClass` on the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` to set the JPA provider.

Comment: Neither of your advice did not help me. This is sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key value of `jpaProperties` is wrong, you should remove the prefix "db.".

```
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```